# web-scraping with python 3.6 and beautifulsoup - getting Invalid URL

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to work with this page in Python: http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas%27

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas%27')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

I'm getting following output:

```
<html><head>
<title>Invalid URL</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Invalid URL</h1>
The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.<p>
Reference #9.8f4f1502.1494363829.5fae0e0e
</p></body></html>
```

I can open the page with my browser from the same machine and don't get any error message. When I use the same code with another URL the correct HTML content is fetched:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchtype=p&action=search&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=degas')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

I also tested other URLs (reddit, google, ecommerce sites) and didn't encounter any issue. So, the same code works with one URL and with another one not. Where is the problem?

Comment: Use `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")` in place of what you have. BeautifulSoup expects a string. `page.content` gives a byte array.

Comment: same effect. didn't change anything. with one url it works, with the other not

Comment: Interesting. I've found out that the "invalid url" response happens when I query it from an US based IP address. When I did it from a different one - I've got the desired page source..

Comment: I queried from Germany

Comment: Think yourself lucky. My BeautifulSoup couldn't even cope with the Christie's page, no matter whether I used lxml or html5lib. (I can't believe it.)

Comment: Try adding header to your requests.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website blocks the requests not coming from any browser thus you get the `Invalid URL` error. Adding [custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) to the request works fine.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ua = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
url = "http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas%27"
page = requests.get(url, headers=ua)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 3):

change your **code** as

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
```

If you are using `page.content` then converting byte array to string would help you out, but you should go with `page.text`