# Why can't I extract links from a webpage using a standard code?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project and currently need to extract all links from auction houses webpages. However, the standard code, provided below, only worked for one of them (https://www.phillips.com/auctions/past). For Sotheby's the code returns nothing (https://www.sothebys.com/en/results), for Christie's it returns weird links with which you cannot work, as they result in an error (https://www.christies.com/Results/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://www.sothebys.com/en/results"

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

What could be the issue with these sites, or what alternative methods could I use?

Comment: Some sites create HTML elements after page load using JavaScript. To scrape those sites, you need to have the JavaScript evaluated first. I believe Selenium is capable of that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to add headers to the request so that the website can return something. [Check this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880195/web-scraping-with-python-3-6-and-beautifulsoup-getting-invalid-url). Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are trying to scrape sothebys.

With this particular website you have two issues:

1. Go into your browsers developer options and disable javascript. You will notice, that pretty much nothing gets displayed at all. Pretty much all of the content is loaded using javascript. Beautiful soup does not execute javascript, so to beautifulsoup, the page is pretty much empty. One option, as @Carcigenicate statet, is to use a headless browser like selenium. Selenium will execute javascript und load the page as you browser would do it. (Same goes for Phillips and Christies)
2. Sothebys uses infinite scrolling. This means that not all content is loaded right away. If you are looking at search results for instance, only the first 15 results get loaded right away. The next 15 are only loaded once you have scrolled to the end of the page. You could automate selenium to scroll down to the very end of the page, so all the content gets loaded. Or you could have a look into the API behind the scenes and maybe find a way to request data from the API directly.